# TestNG in Eclipse, Reference to undefined variable env.DOMAIN_PATH

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, testng

I just got a error when I try to run a unit test in Eclipse with TestNG, the error message is: Reference to undefined variable env.DOMAIN_PATH

but this problem does not exist when I run it in Intellj or with maven.

any one experience this problem?

I use Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2), and updated TestNG plugin version 6.9.12.201607091356

thanks.

Answer (score 25):

When I was trying to run TestNG, I got the same error. I changed the preferences in Eclipse for TestNG -> Maven so that systemPropertyVariables and environmentVariables are unchecked, and I was able to run the test cases successfully.

Before

[image: Screenshot of Maven preferences with systemPropertyVariables and environmentVariables checked.]

After

[image: Screenshot of Maven preferences with systemPropertyVariables and environmentVariables now unchecked.]

Comment: This worked for me. It should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue. and for me, it worked by unchecking all the options from
Preferences->TestNG-> Maven.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It works just by disabling systemPropertyVariables under Window--> Preferences --> TestNG --> Maven

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to enable the 'environmentVariables' option at either Eclipse workspace level preferences or project level properties, for example for workspace level: navigate to Eclipse preference -> TestNG -> Maven -> enable option 'environmentVariables'. By default it's disabled.
see more details in [the official guide](http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html#eclipse-m2e-integration)

Comment: Thanks Xuqing, I think you are right, but I still have problem after I tried to enable the feature you mentioned, I will try more configuration and back later.

Comment: please also refer to: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/284

Comment: explained in ticket https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/284#issuecomment-253554671 and fixed in 6.9.14 beta, please update your plugin. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just uncheck System Property Variables from Preferences->TestNG->Maven.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are working with maven project, setting your custom property to some default value could resolve this issue. below is a sample.

```
<properties>
    <environment>local</environment>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <environment>${environment}</environment>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

you can make use of "environment" property in project using below call.

```
System.getProperty("environment");
```

Answer (score 0):

I unchecked everything and left just the argline checked, and this worked for me