# TestNG - Reference to undefined variable ConfigFile error thrown when trying to execute test

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I'm trying to run a test (`@Test`) through TestNG. But when I try to run any test i'm getting this error `Reference to undefined variable ConfigFile`. 
I'm not sure about this issue. Even I googled it out. But still not able to find any solution. So could you guys please help me on this?

I have tried the below approaches.
1. Downloaded TestNG from the Eclipse market place. And added TestNG from the configure build path.
2. Also, tried adding the TestNG JAR directly into the dropins folder of the eclipse installation.

But i'm not able to run any of my test cases through TestNG.

```
Eclipse Version - Mars 4.5.2
TestNG - 6.14.3
```

[image: TestNG_Error]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TestNG in Eclipse, Reference to undefined variable env.DOMAIN\_PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642358/testng-in-eclipse-reference-to-undefined-variable-env-domain-path)

Comment: @SukhpalSingh -  I already tried that solution. Hence posted here. Also, i believe it's not the same

Comment: @Aishu, it's duplicated, here the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32566845/eclipse-environment-variable-error